# Using tree-sitter as compiler's main parser

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, syntax-highlighting, treesitter

Can a parser, generated by *tree-sitter*, be used both for both syntax highlighting and compiler itself? If not - why?

It would be counterproductive to write 2 different parsers and maintain them.

**Note:** I haven't used *tree-sitter* yet, but consider using it for highlighting syntax of my own programming language. Due-to that, I may misunderstand how it's parser actually works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the answer from https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter/discussions/831:

> I think the biggest downside to using a Tree-sitter parser in a
> compiler front-end is that, while we've done a lot of work on
> Tree-sitter's error recovery, we haven't yet built out functionality
> for error messages. So it isn't trivial to find out the exact
> token/position where the error initiated, and get a list of expected
> tokens, and things like that.
>
> Also, the error recovery currently isn't customizable in
> domain-specific ways (e.g. as soon as the word "function" appears,
> assume that the user meant to write an entire function definition).
>
> Down the road, I would love to invest in both of these things, but
> because there's so much other stuff we're working on, it may be a
> while before this happens.

I managed to use a tree-sitter parser for a toy language to implement an interpreter in Rust: https://github.com/sgraf812/tree-sitter-lambda/blob/35fe05520e806548dedb48e7f97118847b531b26/src/main.rs

Having done that, I can't recommend it:

0. (Rust is a bit of a horrible language to do this, with all the cyclic references. There might be better ways, though.)
1. There is no AST, and no means to generate one because tree-sitter does not allow specification of reduction actions (because that again would tie the meta language to the specification language, as is the case for `bison` and C). This means you have to switch over `Node::kind`, a string. Inefficient and incomplete matches everywhere.
2. The syntax tree nodes only store ranges, not the associated source code string, leading to a bit of an unwieldy API, see the uses of `ut8_text`.

I have a feeling that tree-sitter is best in class only when you don't need a typed overlay of the syntax tree.

See also https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter/discussions/831#discussioncomment-5797368 for another experience report.

Comment: Of course, all that is needed is a tool that analyses the grammar.json and generates a typed language-specific shim file from it. Perhaps someone wants to have a go at that :)